# AWS Glue Pyspark Python UDFRunner timing info total/boot/init/finish

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, aws-glue

I am running a Pyspark AWS Glue Job that includes a Python UDF. In the logs I see this line repeated.

```
INFO [Executor task launch worker for task 15765] python.PythonUDFRunner (Logging.scala:logInfo(54)): 
Times: total = 268103, boot = 21, init = 2187, finish = 265895
```

Does anyone know what this logInfo (total/boot/init/finish) means??

I have looked at the Spark code and I am none the wiser and there isn't a mention of this info anywhere else I have looked for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so this is what it all means:

- total: This is the total time taken to execute the Python UDF, measured in milliseconds.
- boot: This is the time taken to boot up the Python interpreter process that runs the UDF. This typically includes loading Python interpreter, libraries, and modules.
- init: This is the time taken to initialize the UDF in the Python interpreter process. This typically includes time taken to deserialize and initialize the Python UDF and its dependencies.
- finish: This is the time taken by the Python UDF to finish execution after the initialization is complete. It is computed by subtracting boot and init time from total.

Now hopefully it makes more sense.

And remember: if possible do not use Python UDFs but try to create a PandasUDF instead.